# How to Solve this Error "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type"

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, winforms, linq

. I get this error: "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type" - keyword select become underlined in blue Can you please advice.

```
   Employee emp = new Employee();
   comHandledBySQt.DataSource = from x in emp.GetDataFromTable("1")
                    select new { x.Id, Name = x.FirstName + " " + x.LastName };
   comHandledBySQt.DisplayMember = "Name";
   comHandledBySQt.ValueMember = "Id";
```

Above code should displays drop list of employees first name and last name in a combo box

Comment: Is this Vb.Net or C#. Cannot be both.

Comment: Can you create a "var" before assigning to data source and see if the error is the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a strongly typed dataset, you can absolutely perform a query on the named members of a table in a manner close to what you have tried.

```
var queryA = (from x in dataSet.EmployeeTable
                        select new { x.Id, Name = x.FirstName + " " + x.LastName }).ToList();
```

From your given error, it does not appear that you have a strongly-type dataset, and it could very well be that your return value is not a DataSet but rather just a DataTable (at least, from my attempts at recreating your error message, I was getting it on the DataTable and not the set). But without a strongly-typed DataSet/DataTable, this is the query you would perform.

```
var queryB = (from DataRow x in someSet.Tables[0].Rows
            select new { Id = (string)x["Id"], Name = (string)x["FirstName"] + " " + (string)x["LastName"] }).ToList();
```

Notice that in both instances you would include a .ToList() call, as without it you get *another* error saying that the complex databinding requires an IList or IListSource, which the query (without the ToList() call) is neither.

Comment: dont forget to check for DBNull!

Answer (score 2):

`x.Id` might need to be made an assignment, eg.
`select new { Id = x.Id, Name = string.Format("{0} {1}", x.FirstName, x.LastName) };`

`DataSet` is not enumerable, so if `GetDataFromTable("1")` returns `DataSet`, you need to enumerate over the appropriate result set / table, eg. `GetDataFromTable("1").Tables[0]` if you only have one result set.

Each element in the enumeration will then be a `DataRow`, which has an index (rather than property) accessor: `DataRow[columnIndex]` or `DataRow[columnName]`.

Comment: Didn't work. Just to let you know GetDataFromTable returns DataSet. I will see what i can do. Thanks anyway.